# Not sure what's wrong with this JavaScript "undefined" check

Tags: javascript

I thought I had correctly followed the recommendations [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript) for checking `undefined`:

```
if(typeof window.session.location.address.city != "undefined")       
    console.log(window.session.location.address.city);
```

But the code above generates this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined
```

What's the correct way to perform this check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the existence of each property:

```
if (window.session && session.location && session.location.address)
    console.log(session.location.address.city);
```

That may log `undefined`, but will not result in an error.  If you only want to log `city` if it is *not* `undefined`, just add in a `&& typeof session.location.address.city != "undefined"`.  We use `typeof` in this case because if `city` contains an empty string or `null`, it will also evaluate to `false` (ie, it is "falsey").  Of course, if you only want to log `city` if it has a value, leave off the `typeof` and just check to see if it evaluates to `true` (ie, it is "truthy") the same way as the others.

Answer (score 4):

`address` is *undefined* so you can't read its property `city`

You'll have to check that `address` is defined first.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof window.session.location.address === 'undefined')
    alert("address is undefined!");
else
    console.log(window.session.location.address.city);
```